# Coverting Latex into Word with equations, tables and figures

Tags: latex-to-word

This question is possibly a duplicate but so far I haven't found any up to date and detailed answer to the following question: could you list step by step the best free procedure (if any) to convert a LATEX file (containing tables, figures, equations) into a Word file in a Macbook Pro OS X 10.9.5?

Comment: Isn't http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106019/89949 an adequate answer? Also: have you tried to use pandoc?

Comment: The dark side of the force is strong in you, hm??? Converting to Word? Why? :-(

Comment: @ChristianHupfer proofreading requirements unfortunately

Comment: @user3285148: Wrong proofreaders/journal :-P

Comment: @ilFuria I have a Macbook Pro OS X.

Comment: Could you comment a bit more on the "proofreading requirements"? The point is, if it **has** to be Word, well you are basically lost. It just doesn't work well. However, if it is more a "Word-like interface" that your proofreaders demand, you should really [consider LyX, as described in this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113982/finding-a-more-efficient-editor-for-collaboration-of-latex-people-and-word-peopl/114373#114373).

Comment: you should at least make a mwe. it really depends on used packages and macros. but generally, tex4ht can convert LaTeX file to `odt`, which in turn can be saved as `docx` in LibreOffice (newer versions of Word can open `odt` as well, but the LibreOffice can fix some issues and it is highly recommended). `pandoc` is more user friendly, but it's LaTeX support is quite limited